# Multiple Master Detail Relationship

Tags: app, app-development

I have just started learning Salesforce and trying to build an app but stuck at this point.

I have a Master Table Country and I need to create one more table which reports X country has exported to Y country, both X and Y should only have the value present in Master Country table. But I cannot create Master-Detail relationship on both fields and the second field is therefore a text type which is not ideal.
any help ?

Comment: you can use lookup because in one object we can only have two MD field and I think you have hit the limit.

Comment: You can create maximum Two Master-detail relationship on an Object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot have 2 Master Detail relationships to the same object on another object, what you can create is either 1 M:D relationship and a lookup to the same object or 2 lookup relationships to the same object.

I would say the origin country would be the master detail and the destination the lookup looking at your use case. If the destination is mandatory you can do this with a validation rule or page layout setting.

See the [Salesforce relationship considerations](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=relationships_considerations.htm)

Comment: Thanks Dave, One more question if you can answer.... I have a object which has a lookup field from standard object (Users). I want to upload the data but while doing so I do not get the option in drop down to map any such relation.

Comment: Is that on the Import Wizard? - the fields are not shown in alphabetical order so try searching further down as custom fields often display at the bottom. Also check field visibility in the Setup.